# Raspberry Pi News Ticker

Tags: raspbian, video, display, omxplayer

I have seen tickers used with the raspberry pi, but they all output to a LCD screen and I would like to output to a TV via HDMI.

I would like the ticker to use a RSS feed, and overlay at the bottom of the screen. The top of the screen would be playing a video using omxplayer with the dimensions fixed.

Anyone have any ideas or know of something that has already been created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way to display notifications on a raspberry pi is notify-send. Notify-send sends notifications to the bottom of the screen with text defined by the user with a command as simple as "notify-send 'hello'" To have the notifications "tick" information of a RSS feed, you will need to parse the RSS feed. An easy way to that is feedparser. Feedparser describes itself like this: "feedparser is a Python library that parses feeds in all known formats, including Atom, RSS, and RDF. It runs on Python 2.4 all the way up to 3.3. These programs can be united with a little bit if python, allowing you to customize the output as much as you desire.

You can find feedparser here: https://code.google.com/p/feedparser/

You can also find more information on notify-send here: http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/tech-tip-get-notifications-your-scripts-notify-send